# Deleting a Int from my ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a `Arraylist: ArrayList<PlayerBean> playerlist = new ArrayList<PlayerBean>();`

from an Object that includes a String and an double (Name  and points).

```
 public class PlayerBean{private String name;private double points;}
```

However for one of my Spinners I want to show only the name (String) in my Arraylist.

How do I manage to delete(remove) the double(points)?

I tried this without any success any ideas?

I am using the swinger for android. any idea?

```
ArrayList<PlayerBean> playerlist = new ArrayList<PlayerBean>();

List<String> namesOnly = filterNames(playerlist);

private List<String> filterNames(ArrayList<PlayerBean> playerlist12) {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(PlayerBean b  : playerlist12)
    {
        names.add(b.getName());

    }
    return names;
}
```

Comment: You cannot remove a value from an object - it always has all its instance variables. You could set the points to -1 or some such (if that's not a valid "points" level) and then not display -1s, or you could add a `boolean` "hasScore" which is false for this particular player. Alternately, you could make `points` a `Double`, and set it to `null` for this player.

Comment: That wont help me.. I will get the player name in the spinner and the value null...

Comment: @user1163234 since you are using the Android spinner, I adjusted the tags on this question (removed the Swing related ones and added the Android tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than removing them, why don't you make a new array List of String type, and assign all the names into this list. So you don't have any points.

Answer (score 1):

Your list contains `PlayerBean` objects and you can't temporarily delete member variables from objects. Thus you can't remove `points` from the list.

You could either use a `List<String>` instead or provide a spinner model that only displays the name. I assume you're using Swing, don't you?

Comment: I am using android(spinner) I tried thi swithout any success ArrayList<PlayerBean> playerlist = new ArrayList<PlayerBean>();private List<String> filterNames(ArrayList<PlayerBean> playerlist12) {
  List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
  for(PlayerBean b  : playerlist12)
  {
   names.add(b.getName());
   
  }
  return names;
 }